# Android Studio: MainActivity.java file is depreacted

Tags: android, android-studio, deprecated, main-activity

[image: Android Studio Screenshot]

Suddenly my Android Studio is giving me deprecated MainActivity.java files for any new projects.
I resinstalled Android Studio, but still the problem is not solved.

Answer (score 2):

Java files cannot be deprecated. References to Java classes, methods, and fields can be deprecated.

The only thing that I see that is deprecated in that screenshot is the call to `setDrawerListener()` on the `DrawerLayout`. Presumably, you decided to use the Navigation Drawer activity template when you created your project.

Your options are:

1. Ignore the deprecation warning, as [`setDrawerListener()` is not shown as deprecated in the JavaDocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setDrawerListener%28android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.DrawerListener%29). **UPDATE** The JavaDocs are [out of date](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=208718). You could change the call to `addDrawerListener()`, which is the recommended replacement, if you wanted.
2. Do not use that template.

Comment: My [edit suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12207961) got rejected, I could see same edit to the question.

Comment: @Raju: The edit suggestion diff indicated that you only changed the caption. I did not realize that the diff would not show the inline image. My sincere apologies.

Comment: @CommonWare, That's quite alright & I understand. Because markdown won't show any difference, but rendered view does.